# VS2010 Publishing preprocessor directive

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Is there a preprocessor directive available when a project is being built when being published using ClickOnce? If not, is there a build script or macro that could provide this functionality?

Example: `#if PUBLISHING  ...   #endif`

Comment: Isn't that what "Configurations" are for?

Comment: I don't quite get it. Publishing happens after building - pre-processing only happens when building. How is the build supposed to know that you intend to use `ClickOnce` to publish?

Comment: When you click Publish, it build the project. I'm talking about a directive being added at this point, before the publish occurs, and not in any other instance where a build would occur.